# How to get the outline of a thick line in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, line-art

I have perhaps a silly question.  If I have a line, very thick, say 70 pt, and I wanted to use the outline of this line rather than its actual path for vinyl cutting, what can I do to change this?  I must add the line has be distorted and I don't want to lose the distortion.  It's a horseshoe.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Since your path is using a distortion, first go to *Object > Expand Appearance*:[image: Expand Appearance]

This will give your path the distorted shape. Then you outine the path using *Object > Path > Outline Path*

[image: Outline Stroke]

Comment: You're very welcome. Don't forget you can mark your question as answered if it helped you.